# Is it safe to create a web application and then convert it to a mobile application?

Tags: android, mobile, web

I want to create a complex android appplication, but I dont have any experience building android applications. I do have a lot of experience building websites and I have found out that websites can be converted to apks.

Link to convert website into android application: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5dlmqM9Oo8

Is it safe to create a complex website, publish it and then convert it to an android application?

Comment: All he's doing in the tutorial is displaying your web app in a Web View element and I don't like the end result. Regardless the complexity of the application, an attempt should be made and any obstacles regarding code is welcomed here.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just a crappy user experience.  I hate using webapps shoehorned into mobile apps.  I'm of the group that thinks a native app is always better for mobile users.